# Why is $this->data not sending to view, but $data is in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is sending data to view in CodeIgniter:

```
    public function index()
    {           
        $data['header'] = "Home";
        $this->load->view('admin_frontpage', $data);
    }
```

And this is not:

```
    public function index()
    {
        $this->data['header'] = "Home";
        $this->load->view('admin_frontpage', $this->data);
    }
```

Why?

In my view file I try to echo:

```
    <?php echo $header; ?>
```

But only when using $data it is echoed. When using $this->data in controller, nothing is echoed out.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely is `$this->data` not defined.

You need to define a data member in your class

```
private $data;
```

and initialize it with

```
$this->data = array();
```

or all at once

```
private $data = array();
```

See [Classes and Objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) and [Properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) for details.

Comment: Do I need to put this code before the constructor in the controller?

Comment: You can put it at the top of the index() method

Comment: @Derfder You can put this in your class definition before the `index()` method.

Comment: I get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC)

Comment: @Derfder Please see modified answer. It is better to make the `data` member `private`.

Comment: why is better to use private instead of public? It could be accessed from url or something?

Comment: @Derfder If you make a member `private`, only methods belonging to the class can access and modify it. This encapsulates the state of the object and no method outside can accidentally modify it. See this question and answers http://stackoverflow.com/q/985298/1741542 and [Wikipedia - Information hiding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_Hiding) for more.

Answer (score 1):

`$this->data` is not defined in your controller. Remember the current page has no recollection of the name of the $data array. Every variable is instantiated as a seperate variable, just like when you are passing on the data array to '`admin_frontpage`', the array is stripped out and every element of the array is instantiated as a variable (i.e. `$this->data['header']` becomes `$header`)