# CodeIgniter 3, pass $data to view: $this->data[] VS $data[]

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, ion-auth

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15295820/why-is-this-data-not-sending-to-view-but-data-is-in-codeigniter) but it can't help me a lot...

Using `Ion_auth` library I noted that the data to a view are passed by `$this->data[]` and not simple by `$data`.

Why? Where is the difference or the vantage to do this?

Comment: do you know what `$this` is in oop?

Comment: Yes I know more or lass... But what is the real vantage? that the $data variables can be used only in that class or what?

Answer (score 1):

Using $this->data means you can make use of OOP inheritance of a parent controller. The parent controller such as MY_controller can set some initial data which becomes available in all controllers that extend it.

There's an example here:
http://avenir.ro/codeigniter-tutorials/creating-working-with-my_controller-codeigniter/

Answer (score 0):

`$this->data[]` That means you have to define the `$data` member in your class,

And `$this` reference the current object, simply the current class

When you define

```
Class Oop
{
    private $data = array();

    function test()
    {
        $this->data['title'] = 'Home';
        echo $this->data['title']; //access like this
    }
}
```

In codeigniter `$data` is an array

In controller you can `$data['title'] = 'Home';`
Then in view you can access it like `$title;`

Please reference [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) oop

Comment: Ok Thanks Jlocke, but I want to know the reals vantages.
For example: In the controller Auth.php (ion_auth library) at line 81 there is: $this->data['message'] = (validation_errors()) ? validation_errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message');  and at line 93: $this->_render_page('auth/login', $this->data);
But if I change $data['message'] = (validation_errors()) ? validation_errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message'); and $this->_render_page('auth/login', $data); the result is exactly the same. So why use $this when is not necessary?

Comment: @FraOre check the _render_page() function and library then you will realize