# Looking for help to make a select statement dynamic

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I want to make a dynamic select statement that can select whatever table I ask for, same with table columns in my database.

**Here is my select class so far:**

```
<?php

   class select extends database{
    // Instance variables
    private $id;
    public $table;
    public $column;
    public $sql;
    public $result = array();

    // Methods - Behavior
    public function selectQuery($table){
        
        global $con;
        
        $sql = $this->sql;
        
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM {$table}";
        
        $result = $this->con->query($sql);
        
        while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
            //iterate all columns from the selected table 
            //and return it someway.
        }
    }
}
$selectQuery = new select();
```

**Here is my database class**

```
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS."config.php");
class database
{
    public $con;
    public $result = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->con = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB);
        if($this->con->connect_error){
            die($this->con->connect_error);
        }
    }
}
$db = new database();
```

What I'm doing so far is connecting to my Database with mysqli then I extend my select class from my database class so I can get the connection and then I want to select all from.

Comment: Is your $table and array? or just a table name?

Comment: You don't need to instantiate your `database` or `select` classes within the class files themselves (i.e. `$db = new database();` is superfluous in the database class file). Just instantiate the objects as/when you need them.

Comment: Also, remove `global $con;` from the `selectQuery` method... because `select extends database` your mysqli connection (`$con`) is available within the select class via `$this->con` (since it has public visibility ... should probably be protected though).

Comment: Dont you have to return the connexion in a class?

Comment: No it's set in the `database` constructor; since the `select` class extends the `database` class when `select` is instantiated `database::__construct()` should be called.

Comment: Yes but  he call for new database there and not where he uses it? this should be one class with 2 function in it for him to understand OOP.   $db-­>query($table) that all he needs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your `select` class is extending the `database` class, so there's no point re-declaring `public $result = array();` in `select` class, it's not even necessary actually.

Second, since you're not using object properties outside of the class, make them `private`.

And finally, since you're dealing with variable number of arguments, make use of `func_get_args()` function.

Here's the reference:

- [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)

Well based on your requirement, the solution would be to send variable number of arguments to `selectQuery()` method and use `func_get_args()` to get  an array comprising a function's argument list.

- The first argument is the table name and rest of the arguments are column names(if provided)
- If only one argument is passed to the function then the `SELECT` query would be `SELECT * FROM table_name`
- And if more than one argument is passed to the function then the `SELECT` query would be `SELECT column1, column2, column3, ... FROM table_name`

So your code should be like this:

```
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS."config.php");

class database
{
    public $con;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->con = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB);
        if($this->con->connect_error){
            die($this->con->connect_error);
        }
    }
}

class select extends database{
    // Instance variables
    private $table;
    private $columns;
    private $sql;

    // Methods - Behavior
    public function selectQuery(){

        // incrementally construct the query
        $this->sql = "SELECT ";

        // get the argments passed to the function
        $this->columns = func_get_args();

        // the first argument would be the table name and rest of the arguments are coolumn names(if provided)
        $this->table = $this->columns[0];

        // if only one argument is passed to the function,
        // then SELECT query would be SELECT * FROM table_name
        if(count($this->columns) == 1){
            $this->sql .= "* ";
        }else{

            // if more than one argument is passed to the function,
            // then the SELECT query would be SELECT column1, column2, column3, ... FROM table_name
            for($i = 1; $i < count($this->columns); ++$i){
                $this->sql .= $this->columns[$i] . ",";
            }

            // remove the last , from the $sql string
            $this->sql = rtrim($this->sql, ",");
        }

        $this->sql .= " FROM $this->table";

        // execute the query
        $result = $this->con->query($this->sql);

        // return the result set
        return $result;
    }
}

$obj = new select();

$table = "YOUR_TABLE_NAME";
$column1 = "COLUMN_1";
$column2 = "COLUMN_2";

$result = $obj->selectQuery($table, $column1, $column2);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    // display it
    echo $row[$column1] . " " . $row[$column2] . "<br />";
}

$result = $obj->selectQuery($table);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    // display it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is simple**

```
function conx(){

$link = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

if ($link->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $link->connect_error);
} 
 $sql = "SET NAMES utf8"; 
 $result = $link->query($sql); 
return $link;
}
```

now you have a connexion lets pass a $table value

```
$link = conx();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table";  <------ REMOVE {} from your table var!Worked for me
$result = $link->query($sql);
if(!$result) {echo 'Failed to query';};
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["title"];
    }
} 
else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$link->close();
}
```

This is as basic as it gets!

Comment: It's arguably good practice to place curly braces around vars when inserting them in strings, especially in classes: e.g. `"SELECT * FROM {$this->table}"` - it ensures the variable is evaluated.

Answer (score -1):

Actually - I don't think you're far off; ignoring namespacing or any specific design patterns for the moment, there are some scope foibles but...

Let's assume a directory structure where you've got your classes and an application file (index.php for instance) to glue it all together:

**/class/Database.php**

```
<?php

class Database {
    protected $con;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->con = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB);

        //error trapping
        if($this->con->connect_error) {
            die($this->con->connect_error);
        }

        //ok set charset; should add error trapping here too
        else {
            $this->con->set_charset('UTF8'); //probably
        }
    }
}
```

**/class/Select.php**

```
<?php

class Select extends Database {

    // Class Members
    private $id;
    public $table;
    public $column;
    public $sql;
    public $result = array();

    // Methods - Behavior
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function selectQuery($table) {

        //since there's a $table class member... 
        $this->table = $this->con->real_escape_string($table);

        //query string
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM {$this->table}";

        //should be some error trapping here
        $response = $this->con->query($sql);

        //result
        while($row = $response->fetch_object()) {
            $this->result[] = $row;
        }

        //return
        return $this->result;
    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

//require is a language construct not a function
// - it doesn't need parentheses
require_once LIB_PATH.DS . 'config.php';
require_once '/path/to/class/Database.php';
require_once '/path/to/class/Select.php';

//build the object and run the query
$s = new Select;

// this should hold your resultset as an array of objects
// though it would also be accessible via $s->result since
// that's a public class member
$r = $s->selectQuery('my_table');
```

This is all very bare-bones though and not terribly practical (but you said it was for an exam, so...).

In reality you'd probably not want to crank up a new database connection for every query so it might be worth looking at `static` class members: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

... or the Singleton pattern (though you may or may not want a Singleton database connection) : http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html

... also encapsulation, `public` class members are not (generally) desirable: [What is encapsulation with simple example in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985298/what-is-encapsulation-with-simple-example-in-php)

Answer (score -2):

### db_connection.php

```
class db{
    private $db_host = '';
    private $db_user = 'user';
    private $db_pass = 'pass';
    private $db_name = 'your database name';
    protected $con;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->con = new mysqli($this->db_host,$this->db_user,$this->db_pass,$this->db_name);
        if ($this->con -> connect_errno) {
          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $this->con -> connect_error;
          exit();
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

### query.php

```
require 'db_connection.php';
class query extends db{
    public function select($tableName,$column = null,$clause = null){
        $columns = null;
        if ($column == null) {
            $columns = '*';
        }else{
            $values = Array();
            foreach($column as $key => $value){
              array_push($values,"$value");
            }
            $columns = join(',',$values);
        }
        $select = null;
        $select .= "SELECT ".$columns." FROM {$tableName} ";
        if ($clause != null) {
            $select .= $clause;
        }
        $s_sql =  $this->con->prepare($select);
        $s_sql->execute();
        // It will return mysqli_stmt Object
        return $s_sql;
    }   

}
```

$s will return mysqli_stmt Object.

### index.php

```
$query_ob = new query();
// The first parameter is required And other parameters is optional. 
// The second parameter must be Array[].
$s = $query_ob->select(parameter1,parameter1,parameter3);     
$r = $s->get_result();
while ($f = $r->fetch_assoc()) {
    // code here
}
$t->close();
```